# Django form: what is the best way to modify posted data before validating?

Tags: python, django

```
form = ContactForm(request.POST)

# how to change form fields' values here?

if form.is_valid():
    message = form.cleaned_data['message']
```

Is there a good way to trim whitespace, modify some/all fields etc *before* validating data?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should make request.POST(instance of `QueryDict`) mutable by calling `copy` on it and then change values:

```
post = request.POST.copy() # to make it mutable
post['field'] = value
# or set several values from dict
post.update({'postvar': 'some_value', 'var': 'value'})
# or set list
post.setlist('list_var', ['some_value', 'other_value']))

# and update original POST in the end
request.POST = post
```

`QueryDict` docs - [Request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects)

Comment: That's what I've been looking for hours, thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

You could also try using `request.query_params`.

1. First, set the `_mutable` property of the `query_params` to `True`.
2. Change all the parameters you want.

   ```
   request.query_params._mutable = True
   request.query_params['foo'] = 'foo'
   ```

The advantage here is you can avoid the overhead of using `request.POST.copy()`.

Comment: That's a feature of the [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params). It doesn't ship with Django itself.

Comment: django has `request.POST._mutable` with the same functionality

Comment: Anyone with privileges, please correct the typo. `request.quer_params['foo'] = 'foo'` to 
`request.query_params['foo'] = 'foo'`

Comment: @mitsu After editing i saw your comment 

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (as suggested by Antony Hatchkins)

If using DRF

```
request.data._mutable = True
request.data['key'] = value
```

In Django

```
request.POST._mutable = True
request.POST['key'] = value
```